# Rails STI - ignore concern when child record created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

My main model:

```
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Concerns::CouponDistribution
end
```

The related Concern class:

```
module Concerns::CouponDistribution
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_create :create_coupons_for_existing_users
  end

  def create_coupons_for_existing_users
    #
  end

end
```

Now I have a child model 'discounted_coupon.rb' which inherits from the coupon model:

```
class DiscountedCoupon < Coupon

end
```

I have added a column `type`to my main model as per STI requirements: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

**My goal:**

I want to ignore the Concern "CouponDistribution" if I create a new `DiscountedCoupon`record.

So I wrote this in my Concern:

```
after_create :create_coupons_for_existing_users unless self.type == "DiscountedCoupon"
```

plots an error:

> undefined method `type' for #

Is there any other way to achieve my goal? E.g. explicitly skip/ignore the Concern in my child model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be two ways of doing it. One is a simpler way:

```
def create_coupons_for_existing_users
  return unless self.type == "DiscountedCoupon"
  # your logic here
end
```

And the other one is like:

```
after_create : create_coupons_for_existing_users, unless: :discounted_coupon?
```

In your model you can write the method `discounted_coupon?`

```
def discounted_coupon?
  self.type == "DiscountedCoupon"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
module Concerns::CouponDistribution
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_create :create_coupons_for_existing_users, if: Proc.new {|cd| cd.type == "DiscountedCoupon" }
  end

  def create_coupons_for_existing_users
    #
  end

end
```